# slide-in animation while opening new applications in linux

Tags: linux, user-interface

I am looking to achieve the following :

- when an application stars up, I want it to slide in from the left of the screen

Is this possible to do in linux ? How do I go about achieving it ? I could not find any resources online, so if anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

I am open to programming a solution for this too. It would be great if i can get an answer on how to program something like this.

Comment: What do you mean "in Linux"? In a terminal? Or do you have a certain window manager in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have control over the placement of the window. Place the window off screen, then set up a loop that moves it over one pixel at a time. Exactly how to do that depends on your GUI toolkit.